# MASM) assembly implementation of recursive Fibonacci

Tags: c, assembly, fibonacci-sequence

I'm trying to teach myself assembly via MASM, below is my first implementation of the recursive form of the fibonacci sequence. I timed it against an equivalent C implementation in release mode and the C implementation was much better optimized. What can I do better? I haven't gotten the hang of how the various side effects of instructions impact the state of registers or flags yet, or, well, most things in assembly.

Assembly:

```
;extern "C" unsigned long fibonacci_asm_canonical(unsigned long number)
fibonacci_asm_canonical proc number: dword
    LOCAL fib_lhs:DWORD
    mov eax, number ; store number parameter in eax register (also used as return value).
    .IF eax > 1
        ; recursively call this function, retrieving the value for the left-hand side.
        dec eax
        mov edx, eax
        invoke fibonacci_asm_canonical, edx
        mov fib_lhs, eax ; store the result of fibonacci_asm_canonical(number - 1) into fib_lhs.
        mov eax, number ; store number parameter in eax register to set up right-hand side of addition.
        ; recursively call this function, retrieving the value for the right-hand side.
        sub eax, 2 
        invoke fibonacci_asm_canonical, eax
        ;eax now contains result of fibonacci_asm_canonical(number - 2), following the invocation,
        ;so add it with the result of fibonacci_asm_canonical(number - 1) which is in fib_lhs.
        add eax, fib_lhs
    .ENDIF
    ret
fibonacci_asm_canonical endp
```

C version:

````
unsigned long fib_canonical(unsigned long number)
{
    if (number <= 1)
        return number;
    return fib_canonical(number - 1) + fib_canonical(number - 2);
}

```
````

Comment: There is not much to micro-optimize. Function calls are relatively expensive, same as lots of loads/stores into the stack. But calls & stack usage are result of choosing recursive solution. Number of iterations is exponential, for n=20 it performs in the ballpark of a million iterations. If you were to implement iterative solution it would only need 20 iterations (for n=20). Iterative solution may also be more susceptible to micro-optimization.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> dec eax
> mov edx, eax
> ```

This you can write as the single instruction `lea edx, [eax-1]`, but your code doesn't need to use the extra register `EDX` at all. The single `dec eax` is enough.

If you really want to optimize code then don't use constructs like `.IF eax > 1` `.ENDIF` (and many others) for which you don't necessarily know how they get encoded.

`invoke`, `proc`, `local`, and `endp` will very probably entail that prologue and epilogue codes are inserted. This is fine for the interfacing with the main program but is demanding on the recursion.

```
push ebp        ; Prologue
mov  ebp, esp
sub  esp, 4     ; Local
...
mov  esp, ebp   ; Epilogue
pop  ebp
ret  4          ; Parameter removal
```

With a separate recursive routine *DoFib*, you can:

- avoid using the above and rely on the faster `[esp]` relative addressing.
- reuse the argument from the first recursive call. All it takes is a second `dec` on the already decremented value.
- pass the single dword argument via the `EAX` register instead of on the stack.

```
;extern "C" unsigned long fibonacci_asm_canonical(unsigned long number)
fibonacci_asm_canonical proc number: dword
    mov  eax, number
    call DoFib           ; -> EAX
    ret
fibonacci_asm_canonical endp

; IN (eax) OUT (eax)
DoFib:
    cmp  eax, 1
    jbe  .done
    sub  esp, 8         ; Room for local storage
    dec  eax
    mov  [esp], eax     ; (number - 1)
    call DoFib          ; -> EAX
    mov  [esp+4], eax   ; Store lhs result
    mov  eax, [esp]     ; (number - 1)
    dec  eax            ; (number - 2)
    call DoFib          ; -> EAX
    add  eax, [esp+4]   ; rhs + lhs
    add  esp, 8
  .done:
    ret
```